# Get element value and compare using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

hi this is my first time with Python and Selenium so please be patient.

I have:

```
<span id="map_x" class="gr een">36</span>
<span id="map_y" class="green">3</span>
```

So now I'm trying to comapare this value like that

```
mapx = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[2]")
mapy = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[3]")
while int(mapx.get_attribute('value')) != 1 and int(mapy.get_attribute('value')) <= 40:
```

I want to do a loop while mapx is not 1 and mapy less than 40 but when I'm trying it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\", line 50, in <module>
    while int(mapx.get_attribute('value')) != 1 and int(mapy.get_attribute('value')) <= 40:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I will be grateful for any help i was trying many other ways, but it still doesn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Its a valid error. The `span` tag has no attribute `value` to extract from `get_attribute()`. It has only `id` and `class` attributes. And if it does not find, it will return `None`.

You need extract the `text` from those `span` tags and compare.
Try like below and confirm:

1: You can use `.text` to extract `text` from a `tag`.

```
while int(mapx.text) != 1 and int(mapy.text) <= 40:
```

2: You can use `get_attribute(innerText)` too.

```
mapx = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[2]")
mapy = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[3]")
while int(mapx.get_attribute('innerText')) != 1 and int(mapy.get_attribute('innerText')) <= 40:
```

Instead of `Absolute` xpath opt for `Relative` xpaths. If `Elements id` are unique you can try like below:

```
mapx = window.find_element_by_id("map_x")
mapy = window.find_element_by_id("map_y")
# OR

mapx = window.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='map_x' and @class='gr een']")
mapy = window.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='map_y' and @class='green']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text` if this does not work we can work with `get_attribute`

do this :

```
mapx = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[2]")
mapy = window.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[57]/div[1]/h1/span[3]")
while int(mapx.text) != 1 and int(mapy.text) <= 40:
    do while loop logic here
```

Also not sure if we have unique id `map_x` and `map_y` in `HTMLDOM`, if we have for

```
<span id="map_x" class="gr een">36</span>
<span id="map_y" class="green">3</span>
```

if it happens to be unique in nature, please use

```
window.find_element_by_id('map_x')
```

similarly for other elements as well.

Comment: I could not understand you. Was my answer helpful to resolve your query ?